# Canada temporary residence visa

Tags: visas, canada, embassies

I recently got an email from the CIC asking me to send my passport for stamping with the temporary residence visa. Going through the VAC website, there seems to be some confusion as to what documents I should be sending, along with my passport:

1. The [link shows](https://www.csc-cvac.com/en-US/selfservice/cvac_application_processing) two different payment figures for the VAC: $31.40 and $36.96. Which one is correct?
2. Only the VAC fees have to be sent to the following lockbox:

   Payments for Visa Application Centre in New York:
   CSRA Consular Services Inc
   P.O. Box 419557
   Boston, MA 02241-9557

Is this correct? Do the fees also have to be sent via expedited shipping?

3. Since I applied online on the CIC website, what other documents am I required to send, along with my passport, to the VAC center?

Answer (score 3):

1. Since you applied online and not through the VAC center, you have to pay only $31.40.
   Note the text there that says "All applicants submitting an application through the VAC must pay the corresponding fee for the service". This does not apply to you, hence, you don't pay the VAC service fee
2. Submit the following

   - VAC Consent Form
   - Original valid passport
   - Original letter received through your “MyCIC account” that instructs you to submit your passport.
   - Prepaid return airway bill from USPS/FedEx etc in order to send you your documents once your application is finalized. You can choose to do this in person too where other procedure might apply.
   - A photocopy of your payment method - cheque or demand draft etc.
     The original must be sent to the lockbox with your name written on the back with a pencil/other instructions that may be part of the letter you received.

Comment: I've applied for temporary resident VISA too but am not seeing $31.40 [In VAC Site](https://www.csc-cvac.com/en-US/selfservice/cvac_application_processing) am seeing $37.89 and $32.27 which amount I need to mail along with my application?

Answer (score 3):

Below is the Response I've gotten from `ny-info@csc-cvac.com`

Thank you for contacting us. In order to submit your passport for a finalized online application please send the following 6 items to the Visa Application Centre in New York:

[Submitting multiple passports (primary applicant plus spouse/dependent children): You are welcome to mail your passports together, have them sent back together, and combine any fees into one money order. Only one consent form is required, signed by whoever is the primary applicant.]

- VAC Consent Form
- Valid passport listed in your application
- Contact information
- Original letter received from IRCC that instructs you to submit your passport, plus any additional items requested in the letter (e.g. passport photos for PR applicants)
- VAC Service Fee for passport submission – 32.27 USD per applicant. It can be paid:

> At the Visa Application Centre with a credit/debit card (Visa/Mastercard).
>
> By bank draft, cashier’s check, certified check, or money order made out to “CSRA Consular Services, Inc.” We cannot accept personal checks. Tear off and keep the receipt portions of money orders for your records.

Mail-in submissions: Your package must include a photocopy of the completed check/money order you are using to pay the VAC Service Fee – the photocopy will serve as proof of payment, and we cannot continue processing your passport without it. You will submit the actual check/money order for the payment by mail to the following address:

CSRA Consular Services, Inc.
P.O. Box 419557
Boston, MA 02241-9557

DO NOT SEND APPLICATION DOCUMENTS, PASSPORTS, OR OTHER FEES (e.g. APPLICATION FEES) TO THE LOCKBOX

- Return mailing options:

A) Submit a prepaid USPS, UPS, or DHL envelope (must be larger than letter-sized) to our office. Be sure to include a tracking # on it.

B) Submit a fee of 20.21 USD for us to create a FedEx shipment (US addresses ONLY).

This can be can be paid by Visa/Mastercard at the VAC OR by bank draft, cashier’s cheque, certified cheque, or money order directed to “CSRA Consular Services, Inc.” **Please be advised that we can not accept personal checks or cash.** You must include a photocopy of the check or money order when you send your passport, as well as the name, address, and phone number you would like on shipping the label. The original cheque(s) must be sent to the following lockbox with your name written on the back with a pencil:

CSRA Consular Services, Inc.
P.O. Box 419557
Boston, MA 02241-9557

DO NOT SEND APPLICATION DOCUMENTS, PASSPORTS, OR OTHER FEES (e.g. APPLICATION FEES) TO THE LOCKBOX

Processing time for passports may be anything up to 10 business days. If your travel is related to an unforeseeable emergency situation please let us know so we can discuss your options. Please let us know if you have any questions.

Visa Application Centre address:

290 Madison Avenue, 2nd Floor

New York, NY 10017